# Issue with Inbound emails tracking in Salesforce

Tags: apex, opportunity, apex-email-service

I have an email service which creates a task when an inbound email comes to salesforce. I have created this on opportunity and the logic is as follows:

```
global class OppsEmailService implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler 
{
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult  handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, 
                                                            Messaging.InboundEnvelope env)
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();            
        String myPlainText= '';
        myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;           
        Task[] newTask = new Task[0];
        try 
        {
            Opportunity opps = [SELECT Id, Name, Email__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Email__c = :email.fromAddress   LIMIT 1];
            newTask.add(new Task(Description =  myPlainText,
                                 Priority = 'Normal',
                                 Status = 'Inbound Email',
                                 Subject = email.subject,
                                 IsReminderSet = true,
                                 ActivityDate= System.Today(),
                                 WhatId =  opps.Id));
            insert newTask;    
            System.debug('New Task Object: ' + opps.name+opps.id);   
        }
        catch (QueryException e) {
            System.debug('Query Issue: ' + e);
        }
        System.debug(email);
        result.success = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine and i could able to see a task created for inbound emails on opportunities. But when the same email is configured on multiple records, the response is getting stored on other record but not on the record which was used to send outbound email.

Can anyone let me know how to attach the inbound response under its appropriate oppty record.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the inbound email include in the body the opportunityId?  If not, what logic would you use to decide amongst _n_ Opportunities, all with the same value of `Email__c`, which Opportunity to pick?

Comment: @cropredy, Without using Email as a matching condition, could you suggest on how to map incoming email with the appropriate opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to think about your issue and how to resolve it:

*Given that a specific email address foo@bar.com could be on more than one Opportunity*

**Option 1 - Delegate decision to user**

- If only one Opportunity matches the inbound email, assign the task to that Opportunity, assignee is Opportunity Owner
- If more than one Opportunity matches the inbound email, assign the task to all of the matching Opportunities with instructions to the assignee that system could not unambiguously assign and that user should accept/complete the task that makes the most sense based on inbound email body. Note that you should be excluding closed won and closed lost Opportunities from the SOQL

**Option 2 - Use a heuristic algorithm**

- If only one Opportunity matches the inbound email, assign the task to that Opportunity, assignee is Opportunity Owner
- If more than one Opportunity matches the inbound email, assign the task to the Opportunity whose close date is most imminent (or some other criteria that makes the most sense to the business like the highest probability). Note that you should be excluding closed won and closed lost Opportunities from the SOQL

**Option 3 - Put more information into the outbound email**

*This assumes the inbound email is a reply to an outbound email from the Opportunity sent at some point in the past.  If this is not the situation, ignore this option*

- The outbound email should include the Opportunity.Id or some Opportunity autonumber field.
- The Inbound Email Handler looks for this OpportunityId/AutoNumber in the body of the email and locates the Opportunity. If none found, fall back to Options 1 or 2